# VoIP and SIP client app in android using openfire

Tags: android, client, sip, voip

How to setup VoIP and SIP client for android app using OpenFire?

Answer (score 1):

I already faced this issue and get it done by following solution.

https://github.com/webnandroid/XMPP-Chat-using-Openfire-In-Web-And-Android

Comment: I need for voice not for chat so please suggest right answer for SIP based answer.